# delay link click on all page links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to have every link on a page delay by a second, so that a fade-out animation can occur Essentially, you click on an area over an image and the image fades out, but if there's no delay, the animation isn't seen. I have 4 areas on this image. Two go to page A and two go to page b. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a great way to irritate users.

Comment: It's worked well so far. The click delay only needs to be half a second. It's an artistic sort of site.

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript libraries, or just raw stuff? (And I'd be interested in *how you know* it's worked well so far. I certainly wouldn't bother to tell you why I was leaving the site and not coming back. Moreover, surely you're not currently doing this, so you don't really know? Since you're asking how to do it...)

Comment: Don't do that. Nothing else to say.

Comment: It sounds OK to me, but a better way of doing this would be AJAX webpages

Comment: First off, I'm loading jQuery. And second of all, I know because a script I've used in the past works well, but redirects any link tagged with a certain id to the same url. I need different url's for different links. And my feedback has come from friends and a professor or two. Granted, my friends aren't visual arts people, but they have had a fair bit of web design experience.

Comment: @salem: Worthwhile mentioning you're using jQuery in the question. :-) I would certainly have posted a solution had you done so, but I didn't have time to post a proper solution without it. Happy coding,

Comment: @salem: Re your comment above with more information: You can *edit* your question by clicking the "edit" link. (I've added the `jquery` tag for you.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var anchor = $(this), h;
    h = anchor.attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    anchor.animate({'opacity' : 0}, 1000, function() {
        window.location = h;
    });
});
```

Comment: He hasn't said he's using jQuery. Please don't give jQuery answers to JavaScript questions, jQuery != JavaScript.

Comment: @Stephen: I don't, and didn't say I did. (I use jQuery, too.) I'm saying, not everybody does, and unless the OP says he does, it's not okay to given jQuery-specific answers to JavaScript questions. May as well tell him how to do it with Silverlight.

Comment: jQuery == JavaScript -> true; jQuery === JavaScript -> false;

Comment: @JCOC611: No. jQuery *uses* JavaScript. So do [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). And a lot of people use no library at all. (More fool them, but nevertheless.)

Comment: I'm sorry you have a problem with it, but really, it's your problem.  The OP said "I'm looking for a way to have every link on a page delay by a second."  And I gave him a way.

Comment: @Stephen: I agree with you, even tho I don't use jQuery. @TJ: jQuery is just like copy pasting plain JS that somebody else did.

Comment: @Stephen: You'll find that I'm not alone about this. I have no problem with saying "and this is about 18 times easier if you use a library like xyz" (in fact, that's why I have the links handy). But answer a JavaScript question with **JavaScript**.

Comment: "More fool them", or just 10 times smarter, if they are able to make their own framework.

Comment: @T.J.  You're just grandstanding your opinion (no matter how many people share it).  Just because I didn't add a bunch of boilerplate text that says "Listen, if you're willing to install a framework and make your life easier, use jQuery and do this."  To be honest?  He's probably already using jQuery anyway.  I'm well aware of the two sides of the fence in this community regarding `jQuery !== JavaScript`, and I'm insulted that you just assume that everyone trying to help the OP by offering a jQuery answer (like @simshaun) doesn't know the difference.  Haggle it out on Meta, not here.

Comment: Whoa whoa, sorry for any confusion, I _am_ using jQuery.

Comment: @Stephen: I'll object to it every time I see it, and again: I never said anything against *you*, you decided to take it personally and get all excited. I objected to your conflating jQuery with JavaScript, and I will continue to do so regardless your inflammatory rhetoric and unnecessary hyperbole. The good news is that @salem **is** using jQuery.

Comment: Just wanted to say, I've used this and it works fine. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Another thought: I just looked at the fadeOut() api a bit more and it apparently has a parameter for a function to execute at the completion of the fade. Huh.

Comment: @T.J. Thanks. Also, for anyone interested, here is the finished site in question. http://stranger.technoheads.org

Answer (score 7):

You could capture (and halt) the link click event and set a timeout to redirect to the link's href attrib after 1000ms.

Using jQuery:

```
$("#a_context a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var destination = $(this).attr('href');
  setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = destination; }, 1000);
});
```

Not sure if that's the best way, but is all I can think of.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it doesn't make my answer any less relevant. It's not hard to obtain the meaning of my code if he wishes to use straight JS. The concept is what's important.

Answer (score 4):

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        aTags[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // fade out here then
            // setTimeout(function(){ 
            //   window.location.href = e.currentTarget.href;
            // }, 1000);
        }, false);
    } else {
        aTags[i].attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
            e.returnValue = false;

            // fade out here then on complete
            // setTimeout(function(){ 
            //   window.location.href = e.srcElement.href;
            // }, 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `attachEvent` after the else